# How to represent big numeric IDs in Java?

Tags: java

In my country we are using 11 digit numbers as national Ids. Which option is better to represent them in Java, long or String (or another option if there's more appropriate)?

**National Ids won't be subject to any arithmetic calculations**, but if we use String it needs to be checked if it's numeric. In both options they need to be checked against some rules such as:

- won't start with zero
- exactly 11 digit
- some algorithm like (first digit + last digit) / 10 equals 3rd digit etc.

Besides, they will be used in REST api calls, so there may be many requests involving them (serializing-deserializing-validating etc.).

**Clarification regarding bullet 3:
What I meant with arithmetic calculations is, there won't be something like (id * 2/3) + 10 etc. Algorithm is just a bunch of rules to check user input without asking government web services every time.

Comment: Can you focus your question?

Comment: Whatever option that best suites your needs heh

Comment: I would use String in such scenarios and the reason being that I can easily use Apache Common libraries to validate if String is numeric or not and check whether first digit of string is not zero and so on.

Comment: `String` would help in all those requirements

Answer (score 4):

There are two separate questions here:

- Java code: I would encapsulate the concept of ID in a class of its own - once you've done that you can choose whatever internal representation you think is better, and you can even change it down the road
- serialization: you mention REST - it is a text format so the REST message will contain a string representation

Something like:

```
class Id {
  //internal representation
  long id;
  //or
  String id;

  //public methods
  String getIdAsString();

  //factory or use constructors
  static Id of(String id) //include validation code
  static Id of(long id); //include validation code
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A string is better for the arithmetic you want to do for your last bullet point. It's easier to get a character at an index and convert it to an int than getting the value at a certain place in a digit.

Comment: supporting this answer, see the apache commons library, it can do lots of operations on strings http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned:

> National Ids won't be subject to any arithmetic calculations

but then you write:

> some algorithm like (first digit + last digit) / 10 equals 3rd digit
>   etc.

If you need to do arithmetics and check if it's numeric it's always better to use Long than String.
Also, if I will need to check values on specific positions, and the schema will not change, I will create a Class representing my ID and make some regex validation to it.

Comment: What I meant with arithmetic calculations is, something like (id * 2/3) + 10 etc. Algorithm is just a bunch of rules to check user input without asking government web services every time.

Comment: Yes, so this "algorithm" in your case could be simple regex, performed on your own class definition.

Comment: It is probably to calculate some checksum digit, which is common in long ID numbers. These calculations are on digits rather than the numerical value of the code, so storing it as a long doesn't help.

Comment: It won't be a "simple" regex :) I just wrote 1 case, there are like 4-5 rules involving divisions and such, all performed on individual digits.

Comment: ok, maybe not a simple regex - you didn't mentioned the complexity of validation :)

Answer (score -2):

use BigInteger/BigDecimal etc.

Comment: Why on earth would you use BigInteger or BigDecimal for this?

Comment: why BigInteger? Long will be definitely enough.